# Mocha hierarchical fgrep

Tags: mocha.js

I have a test file with a structure like this:

```js
describe('Client A', function() {
  describe("Scenario 1", function() { /** ... */ });
  describe("Scenario 2", function() { /** ... */ });
  /** ... */
});

describe('Client B', function() {
  describe("Scenario 1", function() { /** ... */ });
  describe("Scenario 2", function() { /** ... */ });
  /** ... */
});
/** ... */
```

I would like to execute only **one** scenario of **one** Client, for example "Client C" + "Scenario 5".

With --fgrep I manage to select either **all** scenarios of a given client:

```sh
mocha test.js --fgrep "Client C"
```

or a specific scenario for **all** clients:

```sh
mocha test.js --fgrep "Scenario 5"
```

Is there any way to force some hierarchical selection in order to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--fgrep` and `--grep` match against the full name of individual tests. Mocha builds a test full name by joining all the names of the describe blocks from outside to inside and the name you give to `it` when you define a test, using a single space as delimiter. So if we imagine that your `function () {...}` callbacks all contain a single `it("something", () => {})`, then the full names of the tests in your suite are:

```
Client A Scenario 1 something
Client A Scenario 2 something
Client B Scenario 1 something
Client B Scenario 2 something
```

(And presumably you also have "Client C", etc.)

So you can select only the tests that pertain to the Scenario 2 of Client A by doing:

```
mocha --fgrep "Client A Scenario 2"
```

Comment: Great! One more thing - is there ant way to use wildcards in order to have shorter string in `fgrep`? (e.g. `mocha --fgrep "A*2"`)

Comment: You have to use `--grep` for that, rather than `--fgrep`. `--grep` takes a JavaScript [regexp pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). I suspect what you'd want is `--grep "A.*2"`. You have to use dot-asterisk if you want to match 0 or more unknown characters. The sequence `A*` matches 0 or more `A`.